# Loaded objects in OpenGL have no color

Tags: opengl, graphics, drawing

I have the following piece of code in OpenGL:

```
...main render scene...
glPushMatrix(); 
     glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);  
     glRotatef(90,1,0,0);
     drawModel(teapotModel,"teapot.obj",GLM_NONE|GLM_FLAT); 
     glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopMatrix();
```

where teapot.obj is a file made in 3ds Max and exported as .obj file.
The drawing function is:

```
void drawModel(GLMmodel *pmodel,char*filename,GLuint mode)
{
    if(!pmodel)
    { 
        pmodel=glmReadOBJ(filename); 
        if(!pmodel)
            exit(0); 
        glmUnitize(pmodel); 
        //generate facet normal vectors for model 
        glmFacetNormals(pmodel); 
        //generate vertex normal vectors (called after generating facet normals) 
        glmVertexNormals(pmodel,90.0); 
    } 
    glmDraw(pmodel,mode);
}
```

When I run this example, it renders the teapot object correctly, however the color of it is white (when designed in 3ds Max it had a blue color). 
What can I do to render the object along with its color ??

Comment: Did the assigned material get saved to a file? Does it get loaded?

Comment: Just FYI: this code is loading the model every frame. Unless you loaded it elsewhere, in which case, there's no point in loading it in this `drawModel` function. If your function called "draw" does model loading, you're "drawing" wrong. Pro-tip.

Comment: You were right about loading the model every frame. I initialized the model on the "init" method. Stil, the model has a white color, rather than a blue one. I did not loaded elsewhere the model.

Comment: Could you answer my questions? With an OBJ, materials are often saved in a .mtl file. Do you have this file? Does it get loaded? I don't know about the particular framework you're using.

Comment: Yes, I have the .mtl file along with the obj file. The object is loaded correctly (I can see the teapot model when I rotate the scene).

Comment: Then you'll have to make sure the .mtl is loaded. I don't know if the OBJ loader you're using does this automatically and correctly. Otherwise you might have to do it yourself.

Comment: I am importing the model using "pmodel=glmReadOBJ(filename);" where the filename = path where the .obj file is located. How can I load the .mtl file for this model?

Comment: Once again, I do not know what framework you're using. There is not a glmReadMTL or glmReadMaterial or something like it? Do you have the sources to your glmReadOBJ? If so, check if it looks for a .mtl file and does something with it.

Comment: Also, make sure that you have enabled lighting if you want to use material properties (no matter how you load them).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add GLM_COLOR / GLM_MATERIAL on your mode parameter.